# Security Concerns on Enable of Initialize and Script ActiveX Controls not Marked as Safe for Scripting Settings from IE from Security - Trutsted Zones

Tags: linux, windows, internet-explorer-8

We have a requirement to open Google Chrome Browser from Internet Explorer 8. To do this, we are using JavaScript ActiveXobject with the following code.

Code Snippet:

```
           var URL ="http://www.google.com"
           var chromeCommand = "Chrome --app="+URL+" --allow-outdated-plugins";
           var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
           shell.run(chromeCommand);
```

For this, we need to set Enable  "Initialize and Script ActiveX Controls not Marked as Safe for Scripting" radio button from Tools->Internet Options->Security Tab->Trusted sites -> Custom Level ...

Is this enable setting will harm anything on security concerns?

Please let me either we can open Chrome browser in this way or not, or else any alternative to do this.

Will this code work for Linux OS Internet Explorer?

Comment: Note that adding "urgent" to your question is like saying "I would like some downvotes please". Volunteers will choose questions they like and answer them at their leisure.

Comment: Thanks for your edit and guidlines